# How to configure Ubuntu Server instance under Parallels to have a repeatable ip address

Tags: networking, virtualization, parallels

I'm trying to learn how to use Ansible using Parallels on my macbook pro. I have a target Ubuntu 20 server vm running under parallels. But I would like to have either a static ip address or hostname, so that I don't have to keep editing my ansible inventory file with a different ip address every time I reboot the vm. Is there a good and simple way to do this?

Can this all be done within the vm instance? Or do I have to get parallels involved in the configuration as well?

Comment: Is DNS not an option? Connect using a name.

Comment: I would be fine using a dns name. How is that vended to the host os (macos)? I see no settings in parallels where I can set that. Or do I do it entirely in the virtual ubuntu?

Comment: use dhcp and parallels will take care of /etc/hosts :) a random faq:  https://kb.parallels.com/123300

Comment: Which happens when you buy the Pro version. Plunked down $44 bucks for the upgrade, and everything just suddenly worked; thanks for the hint that got me in the right direction.

Comment: (is Rinzwind a riff on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rincewind ?)